# Assign session value using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there any way to assign session value using javascript

i can retrive the value from session but assigning is not working

```
var TempSession = '<%= Convert.ToInt32(Session["Status"]) %>';
if(TempSession ==6)
{
   alert(TempSession );
   TempSession =1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Comment: i am using asp.net to develop the application. Could you help me with the ajax

Comment: The server side language doesn't really matter. The principles are the same. If you read an Ajax tutorial, then tried to implement a solution, failed, then asked a question about that specific problem that showed the attempt you had made, then someone would probably help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Try using ajax call for setting the session value:-

**JS:-**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TempSession = '<%= Convert.ToInt32(Session["Status"]) %>';
    if (TempSession == 6) {
        alert(TempSession);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebForm1.aspx/SetValue',
            data: '{ val:1 }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("New Session value is " + msg.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

**In your code behind file:-**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetValue(string val)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Status"] = val;
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["Status"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about server-side session then it really depends on the server-side.

It should assign you a session id, usually through a cookie....
That means you could for example make an ajax request to a designated url in your server, specifying the required session id. That ajax request would then assign the session through a cookie.

Another idea would be to actively create a cookie (again, if server supports that) on the client-side with JavaScript with specific session id, i.e

```
$.cookie("SESSION", "session-id"); // Using jQuery
```

Although I've never tried that before.
Note above that the cookie's name depends on your server technology (Tomcat is `JSESSIONID` by default [[link]](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html), ASP.NET is `ASP.NET_SessionId` [[link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#code-snippet-10), under "Note").

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data to the server session by sending it through a XmlHttpRequest. The page or handler that recieves this data can put it in the server session data collection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there this a tutorial on MSDN that covers you case. It is described in [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx), see "Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page" section.

All you have to do is to set `EnablePageMethods` property to `True` on your `ScriptManager` control, then using `PageMethods` object call static method (it should be decorated with `WebMethod` attribute) declared in code behind.