# Accessing Session Variables at server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, serverside-javascript

client side

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getIstekTalebi(id) {
        var istek2 = id;
        '<%Session["UserName"] = "'+istek2+'"; %>';

        alert('<%=Session["UserName"].ToString() %>');
    }

</script>
```

How can use this session in server side in .cs asp.net

Comment: What do you want? Get the session value on server side ?

Comment: `string userName = Session["UserName"].ToString();`

Comment: NOT is working when use above code return '+istek2+' value but must return 2 value

Comment: trungtin1710 must return id but when ı use alert('<%=Session["UserName"].ToString() %>'); alert value is correct

Comment: you can't set the session value in your javascript

Comment: how can use client side session in server side or how can send value in cliend side to server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign session value using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720916/assign-session-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This code alow and working for my question

```
string val = HttpContext.Current.Session["deger"].ToString();
```